Responsive form layout with CSS grid
I am trying to create a form layout whose number of columns depends on the available width and number of items which need to be added (the number of items is dynamic as well and have no common min or max width).
The form structure I am going for is shown on the sketch below. Items can have captions and it all needs to be vertically aligned. Due to the alignment requirement, the flexbox cannot be used on the container.
layout sketch
I have been experimenting with grid layout but I simply cannot find the right solution.
Is there a way to achieve a responsive grid layout or does javascript need to be used?
Below is the example of the code on which I was trying out the layouts, but it is not perfect, for example the 200px on the minmax is also only a magic number.
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="caption">Caption 1:</div>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="caption">Caption 2:</div>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="caption">This is a very long caption</div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 150px;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="caption">Caption 4:</div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 250px;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="caption">Caption 5:</div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 200px;">
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="caption">Last caption</div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 180px;">
  </div>
</div>`

    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 200px)); /* Flexible number of columns */
      gap: 10px; /* Gap between grid items */
      align-items: start; /* Align items vertically at the start */
    }

    .grid-item {
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
    }

    .grid-item > * {
      display: block;
      width: 100%; /* Make inputs stretch to fill the entire space */
    }


The design only seems to have two columns but why have you decided on a flexible number? https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MWRzeqP

an <input> should have a <label> for the description of the input. You should not use a <div> for that! Also, comments can make a code unreadable if you overuse them. If you use comment in a code do not comment what the code does but what the code is for. Any decent coder can read code and as such does not need to know what the code does. If he can't read the code then he can't understand the comment either.

Actually, 4 columns and subgrid might be better. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KKYrMbB

Thank you! I maybe did not describe clearly enough, the number of columns in the grid has to be responsive/dynamic because there can be an unlimited number of items placed inside it.
